# Persist auth state in react/react native for Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using react native for an ios app and firebase for authentication. Every time I leave the app and come back, it asks for a login. I want to persist the firebase login but don't really know where to put it.

I know I need to put this in:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

I have the following signIn function that runs when the login button is pressed on the signInScreen:

```
const signIn = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await firebase.signIn(email, password);
      const uid = firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;
      const userInfo = await firebase.getUserInfo(uid);
      const emailArr = userInfo.email.split("@");
      setUser({
        username: emailArr[0],
        email: userInfo.email,
        uid,
        isLoggedIn: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } finally {
      isMounted.current && setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

I have the following signIn stuff in my firebaseContext:

```
const Firebase = {
  getCurrentUser: () => {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
  },

  signIn: async (email, password) => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  },

  getUserInfo: async (uid) => {
    try {
      const user = await db.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
      if (user.exists) {
        return user.data();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error @getUserInfo", error);
    }
  },

  logOut: async () => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error @logout", error);
      });
  },
};
```

Where do I put the persist code I listed above from the docs?

Thanks!

Comment: default is already local, you don't need to set it - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you check if someon is signed in or not?

From the code shown it looks like you check it manuelly by calling `currentUser`. You have to consider that the persistance of `auth` state is asynchronous. That means if you call `currentUser` on auth before the localy saved `auth` state is loaded you would get there `null` and thing that the user is not signed in.

To get the `auth` state Firebase recommend to use the `onAuthStateChanges` event listener. With that you can listen to auth state changes no matter if you logged in or the persistet `auth` state is loaded.

The usage is very simple:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

That is the reson I asked where you check if someon is signed in or not. If I could see that code I could help you adopt it to use that event listener.

Comment: I just invited you to collaborate on the github repo if you have a minute to look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  Yeah, I read that but also don't know where to put it.  This is located on private repo, I just invited you to collaborate on it if you have a minute to look at it I would greatly appreciate any guidance as to where it would be placed.

Comment: Hi, I have pushed the change to your project. If you want a boilerplate for react and firebase you could try this one: https://www.react-most-wanted.com/ Maybe it would be interesting for you.

Comment: I am pushing that update to my ios app as it seemed to work in metro.  Thank you for the help!  I am super intrigued by your RMW.  It looks awesome!  I will try it for my next React project.  Question: will you do the same with react native and expo?

Comment: Thx  Unfortunately I won't do it for native Apps. RMW is for Web and PWA. For native Apps I use Flutter.